# Java Scheduled Tasks

Tags: java, multithreading, jboss7.x, scheduler

I am developing a supervisory software nobreaks, I am using the API `ScheduleExpression` which is scheduled to run every five seconds,  my code can be seen below:

```
@PostConstruct
public void agendarMonitoramento(){


    System.out.println("=================================================================================================");
    System.out.println("Iniciando monitoramento");
    System.out.println("=================================================================================================");

    upsIndividual   = nobreaksEjb.getCadNobreaskMonitoramentoIndividual();


    ScheduleExpression scheduleExpression = new ScheduleExpression().second("*/5").minute("*").hour("*");

    final TimerConfig nobreaksIndividuais = new TimerConfig(NOBREAK_SEM_BANCO_UPS, false);
    timerService.createCalendarTimer(scheduleExpression, nobreaksIndividuais);
    System.out.println("Iniciado...");

}

@Timeout
public void timeout(Timer timer) {

    for (CadNobreak cadNobreak : upsIndividual) {
        tHNobreak.monitorarNobreak(cadNobreak);
    }

}
```

But I have a problem, I identified through VisualVM that these threads are always active, and are causing a `OutOfMemory` below the number of active threads can be seen:

[image: Threads ativas]

I wonder why these threads are not closed after its execution, and what can I do to solve this problem.

Comment: If `ScheduleExpression` uses a thread pool, the thread objects are still in the pool and thus in memory. You have to free all used resources after executing a single task.

Comment: How do I do this? Remembering that I did not instantiate any thread, everything is done by TimerConfig

Comment: I don't know how to configure `ScheduleExpression` to set the size of the thread pool. You have to search for this. Your graphic shows normal garbage collection behavior - the used heap increases and is freed by the garbage collector sometimes.